# why function variable not working in command substitution inside a function?

Tags: bash, command-substitution

im running this in bashrc file

```
function simplefunc () {
    output=$(ls -1 "$HOME")
    linecount=$(${output} | wc -l)

    echo "${linecount}"
    echo "${output}"
}
```

getting this error

```
Desktop: command not found
0
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Music
Pictures
Public
snap
SoftMaker
Templates
venv
Videos
```

i tried these too

putting "local" before variable or

```
# linecount=$(output | wc -l)
# echo "$(${output} | wc -l)"
```

Comment: Also [don't parse `ls` output.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) Depending on what exactly you want, try e.g. `(cd "$HOME"; printf '%s\n' * ) | nl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change the third line to:

```
linecount="$(echo "${output}" | wc -l)"
# OR alternatvely:
# linecount="$(wc -l < <(echo "$output"))"
```